# Как проверить на равенство несколько значений?

Tags: java

Имеются переменные `a, b, c, d`, значения которых вычисляются в процессе выполнения программы. Например сейчас:

```
int a = 1,
    b = 1,
    c = 1,
    d = 1;
```

Как проверить на равенство их в условии `if` вот так:

```
if (a == b == c == d) {
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (a == b && b == c && c == d)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102548/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy------).